# Javascript SPA vuejs socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, single-page-application, raspberry-pi3

I’m broadly new to vuejs and socket.io and nodejs.

I wrote an single page application to communicate between a nodejs server (running on an Raspberry pi) and a Siemens S7-1500 PLC. Those ones are connected over ethernet and the raspi is getting me an wifi access point for control the PLC with a smartphone, tablet or Desktop.

I’m almost done, but I struggled at that point. I am using socket.io to send events to the client an back. For that i need to know the ip address of my sever inside my vuejs application with is bundled with webpack.

As I get to the point as I was trying to deploy my App onto the Rapberry Pi I didn't found a way to set the IP address dynamically inside my application.

Perhaps some of you guys could open my eyes and give me a Tipp for the solution.

How it's possible to send the IP Address to the client? My Application is running locally and there is no need to do not so. 
In my mind it should be possible to send the server ip to the client.

Thank you for your Answers :)

Greetings Denis

Answer (score 0):

You can use linux **ifconfig** command in order to get your IP from command line of the host application is hosted on. IP is not sth that you set on application level, but ussually is automatically asigned for the given host. So it depends on how your network is set up.

Look for sth like "How to give your Raspberry Pi a Static IP Address".

Comment: thank you, but this is not the problem. I'am looking for a way to send the server ip to the front end, in order to get the socket.io events assigned to the right direction

Comment: But your frontend is set on a backend? I can image that nodejs backend have access to current ip so it can output a IP to js that is part of frontend app and later on frontend have access to it.

Comment: yes, on the backend express serves the static content as well as the vuejs app, i found a wo to do this. I paste the hardcoded server url inside the index.html, but im very sure, that this is not the right way.

Comment: I do not know how to put it better :) Your frontend JS is now static file. That is a problem. Should not be a static file but a template. Backend should use this template to generate the js file that would become part of a frontend. So your IP will be injected into placeholder inside your template. It is the same like generating frontend web pages with html code from backend where some values comes from database.

Comment: Check this: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html And link is to nodejs only since you are using it on backend. The same approach would work with python or any other backend stack...